# "Edited title" in edit that didn't edit the title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

Tonight, I [edited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/6812/revisions) a question to try to make it easier to understand. When I finished, the edit showed up as `deleted 58 characters in body; edited tags; edited title`. However, in that edit, I didn't edit the title at all. I have looked at similar edits and none of them include the "edited title" line when the title wasn't edited. Why did this happened?

Comment: Did you edit it in stages (edit, save, edit, save, within five minutes)? If so, did you edit the title in one edit and then revert the title to what it had been in another edit?

Comment: I just did what @msh210 suggested to this question, and behold: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/1431/revisions

Comment: @DoubleAA I see what you did. But no, I didn't do what msh210 suggested as far as I can remember. (I don't think I noticed the title in my editing — if I did, I think I would have either made the second word lowercase or the third word uppercase.)

Comment: And I just tried this question to see if it was caused by editing the first word of the post. It wasn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code was added since that post was created to trim titles down.  If you look at the revision before yours (since the first post revision), there's a trailing space on the end.  Your edit triggered this code on edit and did change the title...so that's why it shows up as a title edit.

Though it's a bit odd in this case, it is working as designed.